# Creating Recordset with SQL statement

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to create a recordset in Access VBA that will show me all records in a table related to the current record of a form.  My current code looks like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim rst As Recordset

    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select [ID], [Ln] From [Order Detail] Where ((([Order Detail].[ID]) = [Forms]![Order Data Entry Header]![ID]))")

    rst.MoveLast
    Forms![Order Data Entry Header].LineNum = rst![Ln]

End Sub
```

I am doing this so that when adding new records they can be numbered sequentially after the highest number.  When I run the form it get "Run-time Error: '3061'  Too few parameters. Expected 1." on the Set rst line.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is the fact that the string you see there is exactly what is getting passed to the driver.

You need to "build up" the string, like so:

```
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select [ID], [Ln] From [Order Detail] Where ((([Order Detail].[ID]) = " & [Forms]![Order Data Entry Header]![ID] & "))")
```

Watch to make sure that [Forms]![Order Data Entry Header]![ID] is safe content, since you are building up an SQL statement.

Comment: That is, you need to resolve all references to Access objects before you pass the SQL to the OpenRecordset method.